# Transfer layout from networkx to cytoscape

Tags: python, networkx, graph-layout, gml, cytoscape

I want to use networkx to generate a layout for a graph. Is it possible to transfer this layout to [cytoscape](http://www.cytoscape.org/) and draw it there? I tried to simply write a graph as

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(0,1,weight=.1)
G.add_edge(2,1,weight=.2)
nx.write_gml(G,'g.gml')
nx.write_graphml(G,'g.xml')
```

But neither of these is read in cytoscape. I am not sure how to transfer the graph in a format that can include positions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your `g.xml` GraphML file looks good, and loads into Cytoscape for me (I'm on a Mac). Have you installed the [**graphmlreader**](https://code.google.com/p/graphmlreader/) plugin?

If not, download it and drop it into your plugins folder, then restart Cytoscape and try loading the `g.xml` network again.

**Update** Here is some code to add the graphics look-and-feel and positioning to a networkx graph. It is a bit verbose, and you may be able to omit some of the attributes depending on your needs:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(0, 1, weight=0.1, label='edge', graphics={
    'width': 1.0, 'fill': '"#0000ff"', 'type': '"line"', 'Line': [],
    'source_arrow': 0, 'target_arrow': 0})
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'graphics', {
    0: {'x': -85.0, 'y': -97.0, 'w': 20.0, 'h': 20.0,
        'type': '"ellipse"', 'fill': '"#889999"', 'outline': '"#666666"',
        'outline_width': 1.0},
    1: {'x': -16.0, 'y': -1.0, 'w': 40.0, 'h': 40.0,
        'type': '"ellipse"', 'fill': '"#ff9999"', 'outline': '"#666666"',
        'outline_width': 1.0}
    })
nx.set_node_attributes(G, 'label', {0: "0", 1: "1"})
nx.write_gml(G, 'network.gml')
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 for the tip. So I was able to read in the graphml file in cytoscape. How do I now encode the node positions in the graphml file?

Comment: Cool -- I'll give you an example of adding the node 'graphics' attributes in GML since it is a more compact format, and you may be able to translate this to GraphML.

Comment: Just wanted to say THANKS! This piece of code explained just that little bit extra to get my graphs into cytoscape! Now I am able to generate and visualize with interactive probabilities complete metabolic maps.

Comment: Could you, please, say which version of python and networkx you are using? I have problems with writing to gml, because networkx doesn't allow to write a dictionary as a parameter (I mean 'graphics'). And I found this to be a common problem for many people.

Answer (score 4):

`networkx` now has functions to write/read graphs to/from cytoscape JSON format: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/readwrite/json_graph/cytoscape.html

Comment: This function does the same as @samplebias's answer above and outputs it in the required JSON format, except it does not allow for additional attributes. Only name and Id fields required by cytoscape

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition for

```
nx.__version__
'2.3'
nx.set_node_attributes(G,  {n: {'x': p[0], 'y': p[1]}}, 'graphics')
```

The parameter position is wrong...